# Can the fungal form of Malassezia morph into the fungal form of Candidia when feeling threatened? Resistance Mechanisms

Tags: theoretical-biology, mycology

Malassezia feeds on oils in the carbon chain 11-24 and Candida feeds on sugars. I recall learning that when these types of fungus feel they are under attack, they can morph. Does this mean they can change into each other? This question deals with resistance and strategies for overcoming resistance through combination therapies.

"Malassezia (earlier known as Pityrosporum) species form the cutaneous commensal flora, which are associated with varied clinical manifestations ranging from benign skin conditions, such as tinea versicolor, to fungemia in the immunocompromised host.[1] There are at present 14 described species, namely M. furfur, M. pachydermatis, M. sympodialis, M. globosa, M. obtusa, M. restricta, M. slooffiae, M. equina, M. dermatis, M. japonica, M. nana, M. capre, M. yamatoensis, and most recently M. cuniculi.[2] Owing to their lipophilic nature, they colonize the seborrheic parts of the skin and they sustain themselves by using the fatty acids present in normal sebum. They cause skin disease in certain conditions such as overgrowth, descent into hair follicles, or inflammation. Though, by definition superficial mycosis do not extend beyond the cornified epithelium, these organism are seen in the ostium, central and deep segments of the hair follicle in Malassezia (Pityrosporum) folliculitis. Malassezia infections can manifest as superficial localized or can cause systemic infections in immunocompromised hosts."

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4533528/

"The genus Candida includes about 200 different species, but only a few species are human opportunistic pathogens and cause infections when the host becomes debilitated or immunocompromised. Candida infections can be superficial or invasive. Superficial infections often affect the skin or mucous membranes and can be treated successfully with topical antifungal drugs. However, invasive fungal infections are often life-threatening, probably due to inefficient diagnostic methods and inappropriate initial antifungal therapies. Here, we briefly review our current knowledge of pathogenic species of the genus Candida and yeast infection causes and then focus on current antifungal drugs and resistance mechanisms. An overview of new therapeutic alternatives for the treatment of Candida infections is also provided."

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3708393/

"CONCLUSION

Morphological transitions are commonly observed among diverse fungal species. These cellular responses are accompanied by equally profound changes in cell physiology and structure. As noted above, the highly regulated process of fungal morphogenesis represents an adaptive response to specific stresses encountered in various microenvironments, including that of the infected host. Therefore, morphological and physiological plasticity allows fungi to rapidly adapt to changing extracellular conditions. Species-specific signaling and morphological features appear to be a direct result of fungal attempts to survive as new microenvironments, and their particular cell stresses, were encountered (Hogan and Klein 1994; Newman et al. 1995; Batanghari et al. 1998; Sebghati et al. 2000; Gow et al. 2002; Brandhorst et al. 2004; Rappleye et al. 2004, 2007; Gantner et al. 2005; Nemecek et al. 2006; Gauthier and Klein 2008; Nather and Munro 2008; Mora-Montes et al. 2011; Wang and Lin 2012; Wang et al. 2012). The concerted action of morphotype and physiological changes in the context of a particular environment are therefore critical for successful fungal adaptation (Butler et al. 2009; O’Connor et al. 2010). Defining the cellular machinery controlling fungal morphogenesis offers unique insight into our basic understanding of fungal life cycles and pathogenesis."

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4315913/

"Therefore, morphological and physiological plasticity allows fungi to rapidly adapt to changing extracellular conditions. Species-specific signaling and morphological features appear to be a direct result of fungal attempts to survive as new microenvironments, and their particular cell stresses, were encountered"

Answer (score 0):

The majority of fungi grow in one of two growth forms: either as rounded or spherical cells (yeast fungi) or as a polarised branching mycelium (filamentous fungi). Such fungi are found throughout the fungal kingdom and are termed 'dimorphic'.

http://www.davidmoore.org.uk/21st_Century_Guidebook_to_Fungi_PLATINUM/Ch05_01.htm

Candidiasis is a fungal infection caused by a yeast (a type of fungus) called Candida.
https://www.cdc.gov/fungal/diseases/candidiasis/index.html

Pityriasis versicolor is caused by a type of yeast called Malassezia.
https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/pityriasis-versicolor/

Malassezia (Pityrosporum) folliculitis is a fungal acneiform condition
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3970831/

Dimorphic means they can change from the fungal form of yeast to the fungal form of hyphae or filamentous fungi within their own species, not morph into another species. Its clear to me now.

Hyphae - Hypha. Hyphae are a highly polarized cell type and are the hallmark of the filamentous fungi, which make up the majority of known fungal species

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/hypha